Can't Complete Upgrade To 24.04.1 After Original Upgrade Was Interrupted
Machine: Dell Inspiron 15 5567
Op Sys: Ubuntu 22.04.4
RAM: 16 GB
Late last night before midnight I checked Software Updater for the arrival of Ubuntu 24.04.1 and found it available to upgrade. So I clicked on upgrade and it started the same process.
At stage 3 (downloading the actual files) I noticed a delay around the 90% mark. Looking at the System Monitor output, it could be seen that download speed had reduced to a snail's pace. After 30 minutes of this I halted the upgrade process to check my internet download speed. There was no internet as my mobile internet had lapsed at midnight.
Today after renewing my mobile data plan, I again try to upgrade to 24.04 on the Software Updater utility and it shows its availability. But when I click on the button to upgrade nothing happens !
Must I rollback to my system state before last night's attempted upgrade and try again ?
EDIT
I successfully rolled back and got 24.04.1 installed.
Yet I still have no Wayland.
Nor have I got Gnome widgets. Default desktop was Unity and though I changed it the faint Unity look remains. I shouldn't have lost existing preferences for Gnome.
Just noticed that the sound is lost since 24.04.1 was installed.
Pulseaudio latest version is installed.

There is no roll back. You killed the system, should have waited it out. Time to do a fresh install. Of course you made a backup of important data first.

Ah, come on. I had no choice. There was no "Pause Update" button to check download speed in mid-process. And what about atomicity of transactions ? Besides, when I did stop the process I got a message saying that I could resume the upgrade process at a later time.

To be clear. The upgrade stopped. You rebooted the machine next day. You expected to be able to continue the upgrade?

What happens when you type lsb_release -a?  Does it say 22.04 or 24.04?  If it stopped during the download, I presume it actually didn't start installing the files.  So, it should still be on 22.04.

If the description is accurate, you should be able to resume the release-upgrade in a terminal: do-release-upgrade

From a live session, chroot and repair the installation. Search the forum for how to do this.

I successfully rolled back to 22.04.4 as per yesterday at 7 pm. Then I rebooted and sought updates again. The upgrade to 24.04.1 seems to be working although I had a few errors announcing in the latter stages which I was gently encouraged to report. I have phone-camera images of the error messages. XDG_SESSION_TYPE=x11 suggests that Wayland is not yet reliable enough to be the default graphics compositor on Ubuntu.

@Ray 22.04.4 - the version prior to my attempt to upgrade to 24.04.1  Yet after logging this morning my efforts to upgrade via Software Updater just died . . . So something had changed in my 22.04.4. Hence my desire to roll back to yesterday.

Wayland is accepted after reverting to /etc/gdm3/custom.conf default, i.e.  #WaylandEnable=false. Thankfully, on reboot the Plymouth process didn't halt half-way through as with 22.04.4 . . .

Sound recovered after a share of fiddling with configs and restarts.

This question covers how to re-enable Pipewire for sound. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1525035/ubuntu-showing-black-screen-with-terminal-after-attempt-to-update/1525039#1525039
