Ubuntu showing black screen with terminal after attempt to update
So now that the new ubuntu version has come out I wanted install it. While installing it from Software Updater it gave me the message that update-manager was on the dependency removal list. I then checked on google that this was due to me using PipeWire. So I ran the command
sytemctl --user unmask pulseaudio
systemctl --user --now disable pipewire-media-session.service
systemctl --user --now disable pipewire pipewire-pulse
systemctl --user --now enable pulseaudio.service
Then it started some process. I don't have a picture of the process. But then my network stopped working and my Software Updater was also uninstalled. Now my network is not workings so I'm not able to run any commands that need the internet. I don't know what to do. Please guide me since I don't know how to process I am using a Dell Laptop with Ubuntu 22.04 and tried upgrade g it to 24.04: https://i.sstatic.net/ewkx5JvI.jpg

The best and fastest fix is a fresh install of Ubuntu 24.04.1 and then restore the backup of the files you made before the upgrade.
